# One Click Access To Users Account In Wordpress?

Tags: users, user-access

I am trying to figure out a way that my support team can access my user accounts within wordpress.

What I am trying to do is create a report inside the Admin Panel of all users and then have a button that takes them to the users account as if they're the user.

We need this in order to confirm that their accounts function correctly, support, etc.

I know you can't decode the one way MD5 from wordpress - but has anyone been able to create or code something that would capture this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "takes them to the users account as if they're the user"?  Do you mean allow someone to log in as another WP user?  If so then I think you are looking for a plugin like the User Switching plugin.  That plugin only allows administrators to "switch" to another user.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/

Comment: If you need to ask a question in order to clarify the question you should better do it in a comment.